# How to correctly GET an image file from server?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I created an API that connects to a MYSQL database and shows the following: [image]

The urlDFF and urlTXD are the locations on the server where these files are stored. Wrapping this information in an img tag doesn't display any images. How would I go about actually displaying images and files for download?  I am using node, JavaScript, Express and Sequelize. I am a beginner to this and I'm unable to figure out what I'm missing. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Is `home` a subdirectory of the directory containing the HTML file that makes the API call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the browser with a URL it can use to fetch the images over HTTP.

You can't provide a file path on the server's disk, browser's won't have access to that.

So first you need to present the images over HTTP in the first place. If you are using Node.js then the likelihood is that you are using [Express](https://expressjs.com/) (if you aren't, then you should start using it) and using the [static module](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to expose the directory you are storing the images in.

Then you need to replace the front part of your file paths (up to the directory you exposed) with `http://yourHostName/yourStaticRootPath`.

Comment: Thanks! It works but it says the image contains errors. I added `app.use(express.static('cascavel/gta/sa/txd'));` Any idea what could be wrong here?